# How to modify cpu scaling governor in android without rooting the device?

Tags: android, cpu-speed

I am developing a real-time application on android which is cpu intensive. However, when I run the application on some of the Android devices (Nexus 4, Sony Xperia Z and so on), I noticed that cpu scaling governor changes (reduces) the CPU core frequency dynamically when there is a need for cpu for my application.

After going through some of the posts, i found that Android changes CPU frequency at run time due to thermal issues and based on CPU scaling governor mode. It is possible to change CPU scaling governor mode if I have root access.

But I would like to know is there any method to control CPU frequency from an android application running on a NON ROOTED DEVICE?